# why wordpress 6.1 default post editor has different ui than custom post type

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-post-type

I just added custom post type in wordpress and surprisingly its editor page has different layout it uses very simple layout comparing to default post type which use very modern layout. How I can change I am using following code in my functions.php of my theme. I am not sure if there any setting to be changed in admin panel?

```
   // Register Custom Post Type of News
    function custom_post_type()
    {
        $labels = [
            'name'                  => _x('News', 'Post Type General Name', 'text_domain'),
            'singular_name'         => _x('News', 'Post Type Singular Name', 'text_domain'),
            'menu_name'             => __('News', 'text_domain'),
            'name_admin_bar'        => __('News', 'text_domain'),
            'archives'              => __('News Archives', 'text_domain'),
            'attributes'            => __('News Attributes', 'text_domain'),
            'parent_item_colon'     => __('Parent Item:', 'text_domain'),
            'all_items'             => __('News List', 'text_domain'),
            'add_new_item'          => __('Add News', 'text_domain'),
            'add_new'               => __('Add News', 'text_domain'),
            'new_item'              => __('New News', 'text_domain'),
            'edit_item'             => __('Edit News', 'text_domain'),
            'update_item'           => __('Update News', 'text_domain'),
            'view_item'             => __('View News', 'text_domain'),
            'view_items'            => __('View News', 'text_domain'),
            'search_items'          => __('Search News', 'text_domain'),
            'not_found'             => __('Not found', 'text_domain'),
            'not_found_in_trash'    => __('Not found in Trash', 'text_domain'),
            'featured_image'        => __('Featured Image', 'text_domain'),
            'set_featured_image'    => __('Set featured image', 'text_domain'),
            'remove_featured_image' => __('Remove featured image', 'text_domain'),
            'use_featured_image'    => __('Use as featured image', 'text_domain'),
            'insert_into_item'      => __('Insert into News', 'text_domain'),
            'uploaded_to_this_item' => __('Uploaded to this item', 'text_domain'),
            'items_list'            => __('News list', 'text_domain'),
            'items_list_navigation' => __('News list navigation', 'text_domain'),
            'filter_items_list'     => __('Filter News list', 'text_domain'),
        ];
        $args   = [
            'label'               => __('News', 'text_domain'),
            'description'         => __('News', 'text_domain'),
            'labels'              => $labels,
            'supports'            => [
                'title', 'editor', 'comments', 'custom-fields', 'author', 'thumbnail', 'post-formats', 'page-attribute',
                'excerpt'
            ],
            'taxonomies'          => ['category', 'post_tag'],
            'hierarchical'        => false,
            'public'              => true,
            'show_ui'             => true,
            'show_in_menu'        => true,
            'menu_position'       => 5,
            'menu_icon'           => 'dashicons-list-view',
            'show_in_admin_bar'   => true,
            'show_in_nav_menus'   => true,
            'can_export'          => true,
            'has_archive'         => true,
            'exclude_from_search' => false,
            'publicly_queryable'  => true,
            'capability_type'     => 'post',
            'show_in_rest'        => false,
        ];
        register_post_type('news', $args);
    }
    
    
    add_action('init', 'custom_post_type', 0);
```

Comment: What happens when you set `show_in_rest` to `true`? You correctly have `editor` set in `supports` which is good.

Comment: Okay great, answer taken from https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/324221/enable-gutenberg-on-custom-post-type